# Splunk - Use streamstats with transaction command to find gaps in event logs

Tags: transactions, splunk

I need to capture gaps in time between logs for a specific event. I have successfully captured all the logs associated with the event (publication) using the transaction command. In a separate search, I am able to find the gaps in logs, but am struggling to combine the two into one search to find the time gaps in event logs by transaction.

Note: There can be multiple unique transactions associated with a publicationID which is why I think I need to use the transaction command to accurately capture the start and end to a publication request transaction.

This search captures the set of logs associated with a publication transaction.

```
index=test *publication*
| transaction publicationID startswith=(message="*Request*publication*")
```

This search returns the gaps I'm looking for, but only when I narrow the search to a specific publicationID and time period.

```
index=test *publication*
| where publicationID="55432556"
| streamstats current=f last(_time) as last_time by publicationID 
| eval gap = last_time - _time 
| where gap > 3600 
| eval gap= tostring(gap,"duration") 
| convert ctime(last_time) as last_time ctime(_time) as _time
| table publicationID _time last_time gap
```

Am I going about this all wrong? How can I best capture gaps greater than 1 hour in event logs by transaction for a set of transactions instead of having to include where criteria for a specific publicationID?

Ideally, I want the results to look something like this:

```
publicationID         _time                       last_time                     gap
55432556              11/05/2022 14:41:06         11/05/2022 16:44:06           01:04:18
55432556              11/05/2022 17:30:00         11/05/2022 19:30:06           02:00:06
33932543              11/06/2022 08:30:00         11/06/2022 09:30:06           01:00:06
88465272              11/06/2022 11:25:00         11/06/2022 14:25:55           03:00:55
55432556              11/07/2022 12:30:00         11/07/2022 16:30:00           04:00:00
```

Comment: What does your raw data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what your data looks like, we can only guess, but something like the following should work:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp message=* publicationID=*
| fields - _raw
| fields publicationID _time 
| sort 0 publicationID _time
| eval message=if(match(message,"Request.+publication"),message+tostring(_time),message)
| rex field=message "Request.+publication(?<begin>.+)"
| filldown begin
| stats min(_time) as start max(_time) as end by begin publicationID
| eval gap=end-start
| where gap>3600
| eval start=strftime(start,"%c"), end=strftime(end,"%c")
```

What this does:

- a little housekeeping (keep only the fields we need, chuck the rest)
- [re]sort to ensure we're grouped by `publicationID`, then by `_time` instead of *only* by `_time`
- add a unique identified to `message` if it matches the pattern for being a beginning value
- extract a custom field (`begin`)
- if `message` doesn't contain a value, `begin` will be null
- [`filldown`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/filldown) the value of `begin` (works just like Excel's filldown functionality)
- `stats`-out the start and end times of every individual `publicationID` event set (*a la* [`transaction`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/transaction), but faster and more flexible)
- filter every line to ensure there is more than a 1 hour (3600 second) "gap" (*perhaps this would be better worded "duration"*?)
- format the start and end times for readability